# Draw path on heatmap Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, line-plot

I have a vector **x** with length *N=n**2=625* which I simply plot with imshow by reshaping into a matrix, which is essentially a 2D topographical map.

`plt.imshow(x.reshape((n,n)),cmap="magma",origin="lower")`

I also have a given connected path with the some indices of the vector **x**, e.g
`path = np.array([1, 2, 27, 28, 54,55,56,81,106,131])`

I want to display this on top of the heatmap with lines, to indicate the path. Any ideas on how I can to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`numpy.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) to convert your coordinates:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n=25
x = np.arange(n**2)
ax = plt.imshow(x.reshape((n,n)),cmap="magma",origin="lower", alpha=0.2)
X, Y = np.unravel_index(np.array([1, 2, 27, 28, 54,55,56,81,106,131]), (n, n))
plt.plot(Y, X)
```

Example:

[image]